# Continuous Pagination with node and mysql

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to call a function in a .hbs file which is checking for when the user reaches near the bottom, and two .js files to render and fetch blog posts. I can't work out how to properly use the limit and offer parts within my SQL query (in the `splitposts()` function)

At the moment I'm using the following.

My blog page is loaded from a .js file which renders an HTML page with a handlebars helper. In the .js file for the blog page, the following is contained to get the posts.

```
 const td = {
  posts: await tools.splitPosts(), //this is what gets the posts
  page: await _db.find('blogpage', {}),
  query: {}
}
```

Which is rendered in the same file by

```
res.render('blog/blog', td)
```

The `splitPosts()` function lives inside another file and is as follows. It returns 5 posts at the moment.

```
 splitPosts: async () => {
    try {
      let posts = (await _db.rawSql('Select * from blog_posts limit 5 '))
        .filter(post => post.status === 'published')
      return posts
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return {}
    }
  }
```

Inside my blog.hbs file, I have the following scripts which check if the user has reached near the bottom. My aim is to have the `splitposts()` function called when this happens.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {                                                           
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {        
        console.log('test')                                                              
    }                                                                                    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

1) send start_from variable in first response which is equal to 0+total number of rows sent

2) Send this start from back while making second request.

3) Use it in mysql as limit [start_from],[max number of elements to be sent]

Drawback: You need a number of total rows to stop pagination.

Solution 2:

This will only work if you always have a static number of elements sent in every result except last.

1) add a var page_count in frontend.

2) send this on every request. increment it by 1 after receiving a success response

3) stop pagination when number of elements received < static number of elements required.

On backend

use this page count multiply by number of static number of elements to use as start_from

Comment: How can i link this logic with the scrolling function?

Comment: write this logic in scroll function by making ajax call and post any errors you find